# SQL - Table Type / passing a table as a paramater

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that takes in a table as a parameter.

For example: I have a type `PartsImport`:

```
CREATE TYPE PartsImport AS TABLE
(
     Number_Key varchar(10), 
     LogDate smalldatetime, 
     FullName varchar(125),  
     Descrip varchar(250)
 );
```

Then the stored procedure takes in this param:

```
@PTable PartsImport ReadOnly
```

The stored procedure does an insert into a table via a simple `select * from @PTable`, but now I need to join this table variable with other tables when creating the select statement, but I always get an error message

> Must declare the scalar variable "@PPTable"

How do you select an individual column from this @PTable? I tried `@PTable.LogDate`, but it doesn't like the syntax. Is it possible to use the variable table in a join and select the columns or does it only work with `select *` ?

Comment: Can you show us the actually query used? What's @PPTable? And have you tried using an alias such as `FROM @PTable as P where P.LogDate...`

Comment: Thanks !! The alias worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an Alias to refer to your table, instead of the variable name. For example:

```
SELECT P.LogDate FROM @PTable AS P
```

Answer (score 0):

try with below example, when you fetch column only from table variable then works fine but when you use in join you must use alias name with table variable name.

```
CREATE TYPE PartsImport AS TABLE
(
     Number_Key varchar(10), 
     LogDate smalldatetime, 
     FullName varchar(125),  
     Descrip varchar(250)
 );

 create table PartsImportother (col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(3))
 insert into PartsImportother values('1','ads')


 Declare @table PartsImport
 insert into @table(Number_Key,LogDate,FullName,Descrip) values('1','01-01-2015','aaa','adsfadfa')

-- select [specific column] from [only table variable]
  select Number_Key from @table

-- select [specific column] from [table variable with join]
    select T.Number_Key from @table as T inner join  PartsImportother on T.Number_Key = PartsImportother.col1
```